# Remove focus underline border from Angular Material Select

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I remove the focus underline line after I click on the Angular Material Select element? I attached the code. I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

```html
 <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Selected account</mat-label>
            <mat-select matInput>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let account of accounts" [value]="account.value">
                {{account.viewValue}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: do you want to make it unfocused or totally remove the underline?

Comment: Totally remove it

Comment: you can add ```.mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}``` to your style.css of src folder.

Comment: But just when it is focused! Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following:

**name.component.css:**

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}
```